# Linear Algebra - Find basis for $ImT$ and $KerT$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$B=(u1,u2,u3) \in R^3$

$u1=(1,-1,0)$

$u2=(1,1,1)$

$u3=(1,2,3)$

$T : R^3 \rightarrow R^3$

This is expression matrix (**not sure if that the right term in English**) on basis B:

$[T]_B =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 1 & -2\\
\end{array}\right]$

I need to find Basis for $ImT$ and $KerT$.

There is a theorem that says $ImT = Sp\{(T(u1),T(u2),T(u3)\}$

Therefore I need to find the solution for $[T]_B$

$[T]_B =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
1 & 1 & -2\\
\end{array}\right] \rightarrow ... \rightarrow [T]_B =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right]$

Therefore $B_{ImT} = \{(2,0,1)\}$ However on the answer they receive other answer.

Any ideas, Thanks.

Comment: You have a pivot in the first two columns of the reduced matrix, so the first two columns of Tb form a basis for the image. Im(T)=span{(0,0,1),(0,2,1)} The basis for the kernel is {(2,0,1)}.